# React Native run error whith AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to get an example of an AWS mobile app.
This is repository: [https: //github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-react-native-starter](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js)

I miss an error when I run the npm run android or react-native run-android.

I've been trying to fix it for a couple of days but I have not found anything.

C:\Users\HP User\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

C:\Users\User\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

C:\Users\User\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

C:\Users\User\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

C:\Users\User\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

:amazon-cognito-identity-js:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':amazon-cognito-identity-js:processReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you managed to solve the problem but I came across the same error when I was trying out a few things with react native and I wanted to share with you what I did.

My first error came when my build was failing due to the SDK Build Tools being too low, so I followed SudoPlz's suggestion to solve the issue: [SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project :react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/68#issuecomment-304836725).

The error disappeared but then I had the same Cognito exception as yours.

So I made the following changes and my misery went away:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26 // Changed version from 25 to 26
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.3' // Used tools version >= 26.0.1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the above does not make the Cognito exceptions go away, you could try running `npm uninstall amazon-cognito-identity-js` in your package and do `react-native unlink amazon-cognito-identity-js` if you have it in your package.json's dependencies and you had linked it previously.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: where to add your code?